# QGraphicsRectItem set image crashes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6, qgraphicsitem

I am investigating how to set a map image into a `QGraphicsRectItem` object within a `QGraphicsScene` object, and I get a clean crash in PyQT5.

The code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import smopy
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt


class MapWidget(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MapWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setRect(0.0, 0.0, 800, 600)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsSelectable | self.ItemIsMovable)
        self.image = None

        # get map
        map = smopy.Map((42., -1., 53., 3.), z=11, tilesize=48)
        img = ImageQt(map.img)
        self.image = QPixmap.fromImage(img)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(0, 0), self.image)


class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.map = MapWidget()

        self.scene.addItem(self.map)

        self.resize(1200, 800)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output message is:

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting it to `PIL`, it can be converted to `numpy` and loaded to `QImage`. On the other hand, it is better to use `QGraphicsPixmapItem` because it repaints correctly.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import smopy


class MapWidget(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MapWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsSelectable | self.ItemIsMovable)

        # get map
        map = smopy.Map((42., -1., 53., 3.), z=11, tilesize=48)
        numpy_image= map.to_numpy()
        img = QImage(numpy_image.data, *numpy_image.shape[1::-1], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.map = MapWidget()
        self.scene.addItem(self.map)
        self.resize(1200, 800)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]